# Wordpress the_loop and the_post admin side - download html

Tags: wordpress, download, admin

I'm trying to force a download of html admin side in wordpress.

I have the following code which work correctly when executed admin side as part of a admin_menu_page().

```
$wp_querya = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_querya->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $wp_querya->have_posts() ) : $wp_querya->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="section" id="post_<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </div>
 <?php endwhile;
}
```

However in order to force a download, I need to hook in before that, so when executing the same code but from within the action plugins_loaded() it stops executing at the_post().  All content within the loop is therefore not generated.

I only want to force a download of what is in the loop and not all the admin menu bars that normally surround the page.

How would I go about doing this? I am creating this as part of a plugin I am working on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will stop someone going insane, I'm not sure why this work and the above doesn't but it solves the problem.  If someone knows why feel free to add the reason.

```
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="section" id="post_<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </div>
 <?php endwhile;
}
```

Comment: "Important: You must make use the global $post variable to pass the post details into this function, otherwise functions like the_title() don't work properly..." https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata for the original code to work you could echo the object properties like so: `echo $wp_querya->post_title;` instead of `the_title();`

Comment: I did try global $post as well as get_posts($args) in conjunction with setup_postdata($post) in a foreach, neither could get passed the_post().

Comment: When you say neither get past the post what do you mean?  Are you getting an error?  Outputting blank tags?